# multithreaded program in a single processor system

Tags: mysql, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a threading question.

Let say I have a single core processor and a single threaded program and the same program multithreaded.

Can I safely assume that in a single processor systems a single threaded program will run much better than a multithreaded program in cases when the threads is continuously doing some work and not waiting or sleeping?

Also for a multi core processors systems will it change? Since its a multithreaded program and not multi process program. Can threads from same process utilize the multiprocessors of the system or they will run in the same processor? If they run in the same processor then above answer will satisfy this question

This question came to my mind when I was working with mysql. In mysql there is a single process and multiple threads for each connection, right?
If that is the case then in single processors system, If I run 2 queries simultaneously, then it will take more time than running the 2 queries one after the other?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple threads can use multiple processors.

If this speeds up the application: Depends on the application. Locking over multiple processors is VERY expensive. So if you need a lot of synchronization between your threads then this will become a bottleneck. If each thread can work for itself, this will definitely speed up the application.

Also on a single processor system: Using multiple threads will slow down overall speed (if only doing work) but will usually improve response time (since the main goal on such systems is to do work in a worker thread while keeping the GUI responsive).

With MySql I'm not an expert. Basically if you do two queries (read only access!) then they should be faster. If you do write access, the queries may need to be synchronized (and probably will run slower).

Additionally you need to ensure that the DB itself is multi-threading safe for the required access (there's always a tradeoff between speed and safety...). If you need a lot of mutations, sometimes using a single thread is faster...

Answer (score 0):

On a single processor system, the underlying natural way programs run is single threaded. Please also understand that with the advent of DMA, no system remains a single processor/core, since DMA works in "parallel" (though the memory arbitrator is continously deciding who goes next implementing some kind of locking) with the main program.

Also, eliminating multithreading from programs eliminates costly context switching and locking overheads. So, you are right a single threaded program will run faster on a single processor system.

On a multiprocessor/core, if your multithreaded/multiprocess program(s) do a lot of locking, the speed would reduce to a great extent. But please note, the locking is already in place by the hardware, i.e. the memory arbitrator, so the speed gains don't multiply with the number of processors as it may first appear.